# How to extract complex log data to excel

Tags: excel, logging, text

I have some data that looks like this

```
GlobalCarrierBranchId: 2, Direction: UL, RequestedCapacity: 4, IqDelay: 15289[ns]
GlobalCarrierBranchId: 3, Direction: UL, RequestedCapacity: 4, IqDelay: 15289[ns]
GlobalCarrierBranchId: 0, Direction: DL, RequestedCapacity: 4, IqDelay: 32654[ns]
GlobalCarrierBranchId: 1, Direction: DL, RequestedCapacity: 4, IqDelay: 32654[ns]
```

And I'd like to import it into excel and have it look like this

```
GlobalCarrierBranchId Direction RequestedCapacity IqDelay [ns]
2                     UL        4                 15289
3                     UL        4                 15289
0                     DL        4                 32654
1                     DL        4                 32654
```

I'm not sure if excel can do it or if I need another application or script. Any ideas?

Comment: vba would be the best for this.  But outside that look into Text to Columns using the comma,space and colon as delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your low hanging fruit solution: open your data in Word, do a replace all of ", " for "^t". This will replace all your commas with Tabs. Then copy your data to Excel and it will interpret the tab separations as different columns. Finally save your sheet.